# how to have mysql ignore special character in names

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a CSV bulk import of names into MYSQL, but during the process there is a special characters that halts the operation.

The character over the name - Pérez

Is there a way to have MYSQL to ignore this on upload?
My next step is to automate the upload via a web page where a customer can just upload  the CSV file and hit submit, therefore hoping to work out these glitches.

I took the suggestion of the panel and recreated my table as UTF8-Default.

ERROR 1366: Incorrect string value: '\xE9rez' for column 'acct_owner' at row 1
SQL Statement:

I tried this and I still get the same error on that special character, plus now for some reason my auto-increment column does not increment, it just captures the data from the last_update column, therefore everything shifts left.

Comment: There is missing information here. What query are you using for your bulk import, which charset is used by the file, what does mysql tell you when it decides to stop etc?

Comment: Do you have any code, does it halt or does it throw an error, please provide more information..

Comment: This should not stop data import instead just change it as your column seems latin1 intead of utf-8.

Comment: are you able to import csv data by same command after removing this keyword...

Comment: Why ignore when you can insert with encoding ! any specific reason?

Comment: New to using MYSQL, therefore I am using MYSQL Workbench to do my dirty work. Therefore wasn't sure what to do. I will try converting the column to UTF-8 and try it. Stay tuned.

Comment: I recreated my entire table, using UTF8-Default and then retried to upload, here is what I got for an error  -ERROR 1366: Incorrect string value: '\xE9rez' for column 'acct_owner' at row 1

Comment: `\xE9` looks like latin1, not utf8.

Answer (score 0):

Well in case you want to `insert/load` csv data with special character you can try like this

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv'
IGNORE INTO TABLE table
CHARACTER SET UTF8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this I ended up rebuilding my DB tables, i then went ahead and prior to submitting my data I cycled through it with some code to remove the characters that I know are causing me problems. While might not be the best way it was certainly the easiest way i found. I initially had a cycle that removed any characters that were not standard A-Z or 0-9 but I discovered that caused me other problems as I needed to see ; and \ and even / in some of my details. Therefore I only concentrated on what I know was breaking the import to MYSQL.

Here is a snip of the code i used:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

//Replace all the special characters to avoid any insert errors
$data = preg_replace('/\'/', '', $data);
$data = preg_replace('/é/', 'e', $data);

if($firstRow) { $firstRow = false; }
else {

    $import="INSERT INTO ..... blah blah blah....
```